# Return min value from query with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table:

table POI:

### NAME | VOTE

Paris | rt_1

Milan | rt_2

Rome  | rt_3

### ...   | ...

table rtgitems:

### ITEM | TOTALRATE

rt_1 | 22

rt_2 | 3

rt_3 | 3

rt_4 | 5

### ...  | ...

I want the attribute NAME from first table with minimum value in TOTALRATE from second table. Example: Milan, Rome.

I use this query:

```
SELECT POI.Name FROM POI INNER JOIN rtgitems ON POI.Vote=rtgitems.item WHERE POI.Vote = (SELECT MIN(rtgitems.totalrate) FROM rtgitems)
```

but don't work, I have empty result.
How must I do?
Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT POI.Name FROM POI INNER JOIN  rtgitems ON POI.Vote=rtgitems.item WHERE POI.Vote = (SELECT  item FROM rtgitems ORDER BY totalrate DESC LIMIT 1)`. You are returning `totalrate` in your subquery,  but you need the `item`  for `WHERE POI.Vote = ...`

Comment: This work but isn't that I want. I want the name of ONLY POI that have minimum rate, in the table of up Milan and Rome.

Comment: Sorry, try `SELECT POI.Name FROM POI INNER JOIN rtgitems ON POI.Vote=rtgitems.item WHERE rtgitems.totalrate = (SELECT MIN(totalrate) FROM rtgitems)` - sqlfiddle -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6198f3/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you are using min or max kind or function in your sql you should use group by clause to get the real output from the table.

```
SELECT POI.Name FROM POI INNER JOIN rtgitems ON POI.Vote=rtgitems.item where totalrate= (select min(totalrate) from rtgitems)
GROUP BY POI.Name
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I want that the query result ONLY the POI with minimum rate. In the example of up: Milan, Rome.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT POI.Name, min(totalrate) FROM POI INNER JOIN rtgitems ON POI.Vote=rtgitems.item
GROUP BY POI.Name
```

Comment: Thanks but I want that the query result ONLY the POI with minimum rate. In the example of up: Milan, Rome.

Answer (score 0):

try `SELECT POI.name FROM POI join rtgitems ON POI.vote=rtgitems.item where totalrate<=(SELECT totalrate from rtgitems order by totalrate desc limit 1)`